# ActiveCollab Project management section - adding extra custom fields while add/edit

Tags: project, field, activecollab

I'm trying to develop a custom module inside ActiveCollab(4.0.11) for adding some extra fields while adding/editing projects. ActiveCollab itself has ability to add only 3 custom fields, but I need to add more fields(text,dropdown etc). I have gone through the documentation of creating modules and started working on it, but did not get much details. I have used "on_project_created" event to trigger my custom module to capture the Project form data(added the required custom fields in to ActiveCollab database tables tables and it started showing on project add/edit form automatically). Now I'm stuck with not knowing how to pass the posted values from Handler function to Controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

activeCollab supports only three custom fields and there is no officially supported way to programatically add more fields. Exploiting internal API-s may work, but it is not recommended. These API-s may change or even disappear at any point, without prior notice.